# Regular Continuous-Time Markov Chain with Finite State Space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a Continuous-Time Markov Chain (CTMC) $\{X(t):t \ge 0 \}$ on a finite state space $S$ (i.e. $|S|<\infty$). Let $T_i$ denote the holding time in state $i$ which is an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda_i$. Suppose $\lambda_i < U$, i.e., $\lambda_i$ for all states is bounded. Prove that the above CTMC is regular.
I appreciate any comment/hint.

- Note 1: We know a regular CTMC is defined to be a CTMC such that with probability $1$, the number of jumps in any finite time interval is finite.
- Note 2: my attempt: I know how to prove the regularity for CTMCs with infinite state space. We can show $\sum_{i\in S} T_i$ is infinite with probability 1. This is because $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i\in S} T_i] = \sum_{i\in S} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} > \sum_{i\in S} \frac{1}{U} = |S|/U$. So, if $|S|=\infty$, we have $\sum_{i\in S} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} = \infty$, and this implies that the CTMC is regular. However, I don't know to proceed for a finite state space.

Comment: Since $S$ is finite, $\{\lambda_{i} \, \mid \, i \in S\}$ is automatically bounded.  (There is no need to make it an assumption.)  The argument in Note 2 will work if you replace $\sum_{i \in S} T_{i}$ by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_{n}$, where $S_{n}$ is the $n$th holding time of the chain.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterMorfe for your comment. Could you explain a bit more?
1- I do not quite get why $\lambda_i$ is automatically bounded. Suppose there are only two states $S=\{1,2\}$. Isn't it possible that $\lambda_1$ is unbounded? My understanding is that $\lambda_i$ can take any nonnegative value, independent of the state space.
2- As I defined in the question, $T_i$ is the holding time of state $i$. Could you please further clarify what does $S_n$ mean in your answer? Is it related to the underlying DTMC?

Comment: See the discussion on Regularity here: https://www.randomservices.org/random/markov/Continuous.html

Comment: Thank you @Math1000. The discussion is nice.